# App not requesting permissions on install

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions

I am installing an app over ADB from my build environment.  I am deploying to a physical Nexus 7.  (When deploying to an emulator, there is no problem)

When I deploy, the install appears to succeed, but when the initial intent is lost I get a permission error.

```
[2012-12-02 23:24:04 - KillerAppRejji] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException:
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=
android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.killerapprejji/.SplashScreen }
from null (pid=6116, uid=2000) requires android.permission.NFC
```

EDIT: updated manifest.xml with changes to  as opposed to

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.killerapprejji"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.NFC" 
              android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ninjahead"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:allowClearUserData="true" android:logo="@drawable/ninjahead" android:persistent="true" android:permission="android.permission.NFC">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
          <data android:mimeType="application/com.killerapprejji.NfcHandle"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>  
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AttackActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/attack_button"></activity>
    <activity android:launchMode="standard" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/menu_settings" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:noHistory="false" android:description="@string/menu_settings" android:configChanges="keyboard" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:parentActivityName="@string/title_activity_main" android:icon="@drawable/ninjahead" android:name=".SetInfo"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DefendActivity" android:label="@string/defend_button" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    <activity android:name="DisplayInteractions" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/Stats" android:parentActivityName="@string/title_activity_main"></activity>
    <activity android:name="NfcHandle">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/com.killerapprejji.NfcHandle"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `<uses-permission ... />` rather than `<permission ... />`

Comment: Tried this but it did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />` in your manifest, you are instead making your own permission with the `<permission>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

My issue arrises from the

```
<application ... **android:permission="android.permission.NFC">**
```

When I removed the bolded area, I was able to install the app and run the installed app.